# Mule app deployment reports invalid content was found starting with element

Tags: deployment, mule

I have two mule flows built using "Anypoint" studio and they run perfectly fine on my mac when i build it. I want to now deploy this app on to a mule standalone runtime. I picked up all the files under /target directory and packaged it as an app and copied it under /apps/ directory. When i start mule, i get an exception that states "invalid content was found starting with element ". How do i deploy my flows to a mule standalone runtime ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Anypoint Studio you can do a right click on the project and select "Export" then pick the "Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive". That will generate a zip file you can put in the apps directory.
Keep in mind that some of the features from Anypoint Studio, like Datamapper, will only work in a EE version of Mule standalone.

Comment: Thanks afelisatti. I am getting the same exception. Invalid content was found starting with element 'ee:object-store-caching-strategy' . Is object-store-caching-strategy part of EE version of Mule as well ?

Comment: Yes. The "ee" indicates so.